# Is it possible to create a self-signed intermediate CA for ssl?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I am trying to create my own SSL hierarchy like:

> MyRootCA
>
> --MyIntermediateCA
>
> ----MyCert

I have installed MyRootCA and MyIntermediateCA, but windows points out that MyIntermediateCA doesn't have the right to issue certs. Therefore it invalidates MyCert.

[image]

[image]

I am using sign.sh from mod_ssl package, which utilizes openssl ca command.

I wonder if there is any parameter/option that grants MyIntermediateCA the right to issue sublevel certs?

Answer (score 2):

Regularly an intermediate CA needs a valid signature (also not expired) from a trusted CA and also the usage restriction tag CA:true. Normally intermediate CAs are not directly listed in the trust database by verifying clients. Therefore, when a service sends its own certificate which is signed by an intermediate CA (for example when establishing a TLS session) it should also send all the intermediate CA certificates between itself and the root CA, so the verifying client can actually build a trust chain between the two ends of the chain.

A self-signature, as you are talking about in the title of your question, would make this either a stand-alone certificate or if it has the CA:true flag it would make the certificate a root CA itself.